# Can voice biometrics, (specifically voice recognition) application be used at windows logon screen?

Tags: programming-languages, authentication

I'm planning to develop an application in C# programming language for user authentication.

Target platform = Newer Windows versions such as Windows 8/10.

Your kind answers will be much appreciated. Cheers!

Comment: Sounds like an interesting project but I don't see what your this has to do with computer _science_.

Comment: @David - Thanks for showing interest in my project. Im a computer science student and im choosing this topic as my Final Year Project. So im thinking to integrate voice biometrics in it, (specifically voice recognition) rather than speech recognition.

Comment: Sorry, but if that's your final project, you are probably not getting computer *science* education. Unless you develop the whole voice recognition yourself.

Comment: Simply - no. Sorry, voice recognition is not at the stage of unique identification, too much false positives and false negatives. You should research the field of interest, check for limitations and/or make your own attempt - which is a lot for one semester since many people research this field advancing techniques but are not yet there. And the mere planning of making a project is neither Computer Science nor programming yet.

Comment: Actually the purpose of creating the project is to either develop the application together with the voice recognition algorithms (from scratch) or either just incorporate the 'ready-made' algorithm and incorporate it in the application being developed.